# Is an ASP.NET site in a Linux environment possible?

Tags: asp.net, linux

I found some software a while ago that claimed to execute ASP.NET applications on a Linux server, I remember that the information said that takes the code and converts it to Java. I never downloaded or tested the software. Does anyone know the name of this software?

Also, is possible to execute ASP.NET on a Linux server in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series of blog articles all talk about setting up and running different versions of asp.net MVC using the Mono runtime with serveral different flavors of Linxu. My take on it, yes you can.

- [Get MVC3 Razor Running on Mono](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/06/get-mvc3-razor-running-on-mono/)
- [Setting up Mono 2.8 with Asp.Net 4.0 and MVC2 on Ubuntu with MySql
  Membership](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/11/setting-up-mono-2-8-with-asp-net-4-0-and-mvc2-on-ubuntu-with-mysql-membership/)
- [Installing OpenSuse 11.2 with Mono 2.6.1 and Apache Using Text Mode Configuration – Porting to Mono](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/01/installing-opensuse-11-2-with-mono-2-6-1-and-apache-using-text-mode-configuration-porting-to-mono-part-1-of-3/#RunningMVC)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is entirely possible to use ASP.NET in a linux environment using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). I've never done it, but I know it is possible.

I haven't heard of the software that you are talking about, however, so maybe somebody else can shed some light on that.

Comment: I remember that I found the page of the software 3/4 years ago.

Comment: ASP.NET 2.0 can run with Mod_Mono http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Comment: I have never done time travel, but I know it is possible!

Comment: Yep, Mono lets you run .NET even on Apache, I've never used it myself though as my sites have always used PHP.

Comment: Are you aware of any web application that actually runs on ASP.NET + Mono + Linux?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson unfair, at least I provided a link! ;)

Comment: @Jetti [Time Travel](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/traveling-through-time.html), there you go! :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson shucks...foiled again!

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic I am not aware of any sites that actually use this setup. If I'm going to use ASP.Net, I'm going to maximize my potential by using Windows and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

There have been several attempts to provide CLI/CLR compilers to the JVM, but I don't think any one has become particularly popular. See, for example:

http://xmlvm.org/clr2jvm/